# Vertical centering a large image inside overflow:hidden div in Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, margin

I've seen quite a few postings related to this but none of them seem applicable to my case.  I am trying to center a large image so that the vertical overflow occurs evenly on the top and bottom.  The image cannot be a background-image.

```
<div id="container-outer">
  <div id="container-inner">
      <img src="image.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css...

```
#container-outer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
#container-inner {
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
#container-inner img{
  width:100%;
  min-height:300px;
  max-height:600px;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width:800px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid green;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

This works on Chrome, IE, and Safari... but for some reason Firefox doesn't like it.  I'm even fairly certain I had it working on FF a couple days ago but I've tested on two separate computers now and nothing.

Bonus points for uniformly cropping horizontally at small sizes through CSS as well.

and here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kd8bM/1/

UPDATED Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kd8bM/9/ (the code above now matches this.)

Second UPDATE: For clarification, on re-size this creates a zoom effect in chrome, safari, and ie. I'm trying to find a way to get that in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the #container-inner a 100% width and height could do the trick.

```
#container-inner {
    position:relative;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kd8bM/5/

UPDATE:
After the thread of comments we resolved on this being an acceptable answer.
http://jsfiddle.net/Kd8bM/10/

Comment: You've removed the vertical cropping by taking out the top:50%; and the image is now getting distorted. It's not so obvious with the image I chose because it is a landscape; but I updated your fiddle with a building and on re-size the distortion is fairly evident. http://jsfiddle.net/Kd8bM/7/

Comment: disregard the above... mine was distorted as well and did no vertical crop... working on that now.   Here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/Kd8bM/9/

Comment: If you take out the width and height for #content-inner I put in and then also take out the width:100% on #container-inner then the image will auto scale based on the height:100%.
http://jsfiddle.net/Kd8bM/8/

It would also help if your end goal was more clear.

Comment: In http://jsfiddle.net/Kd8bM/9/ I'm still not sure why you have the top:50%;  It pushing down the image 50% down the container is a reasonable response to this code. If you take it out the picture fills the container nicely.

Comment: Try it in chrome and you'll get a zoom effect. Sorry I was unclear.  I had my fiddle working before I posted this then somehow posted the wrong code.  I'm trying to find a way to get Firefox looking like chrome, safari, and ie. The fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Kd8bM/9/ is the look I'm going for.

Comment: How about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Kd8bM/10/
It seems to be working the same way in Chrome and Firefox.
The only difference I can tell is that Chrome zooms and expands upwards, but Firefox zooms and expands downwards.

Comment: Wow! Almost didn't see this comment.  This will definitely at least be a temporary fix for me. I'm using this as a bg image for my landing page so I really would love to get this perfect though.  If you want to make this an answer I'll accept it, if I don't hear from you, I'll accept this one in a day or so

Comment: I'm glad we finally got something that will work for you.
If you want to improve it in some way feel free to start a chat or open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure I got your question, but I tried your fiddle in FF and Chrome to see the difference. I see the image is not aligned the same way in FF as it is in Chrome. You could try placing the image in outer DIV and not inside inner DIV. That would align the image properly in all browsers.

```
<div id="container-outer">
<div id="container-inner">
    </div>
    <img id="img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/800x600_Wallpaper_Blue_Sky.png" />

</div>

#img{
 width:100%;
min-height:300px;
max-height:600px;
min-width: 400px;
max-width:800px;
margin:auto;
position: absolute;
border: 2px solid green;
left: 0;
top:-50%;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had set the height to 100% as well as the width which completely undid the effect I was going for. It's been updated here http://jsfiddle.net/Kd8bM/9/

Comment: Try setting top to -50% for the image. I have edited my answer. Seems to work for me in Firefox and Chrome both.

Comment: I may be missing something simple, but I can't seem to get this to center inside an overflow:hidden div here is my crack at using your code http://jsfiddle.net/Kd8bM/12/ I placed the img inside the #container-inner. You can see how at small sizes it comes off the bottom of its container div

Comment: It works if you place the **img outside inner container**. Here's your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kd8bM/14/) updated.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Unfortunately, on my site I can only have this item take up a specific amount of space, hence the container div which is set to Height:300px, Overflow:Hidden.

Comment: The height of container-outer is 300px, and the img would be **inside container-outer** and not inside container-inner, that limits the height of the image.

Comment: container-inner vs outer doesn't matter since there was no css on the outer in my fiddle. I think the issue comes from top:-50% being calculated based on its container div. I need overflow:hidden on that div and in order to contain the image it has to have position:relative height:300px. For more what I was going for, check out user2938649's fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Kd8bM/10/ it functions as expected in chrome etc, but looks better in ff.

Comment: In this case, it matters which DIV you place the image in, because both have position:relative and FF places the absolute positioned image in relative to its parent with position:relative. Glad you got what you wanted from other answers!